# Best method of persisting API data when using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, react-hooks

I have a problem with latency with my current React application. As it currently is written, I have a top level react-router which routes between several protected routes. Like so:

```
export default function IndexRouter(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/routeA" component={ComponentA} />
      <Route path="/routeB" component={ComponentB} />
      <Route path="/routeC" component={ComponentC} />
       ...
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Component A loads a lot of data from several API calls, including multiple data arrays and images. This is done with a custom Axios hook. The approximate structure of component A is as follows:

```
export default function ComponentA(): JSX.Element {
  const [data, loading, error, fetch] = useAxios(...);
  return (
    <Sub1 />
    <Sub2 />
  );
}
export default function Sub1(): JSX.Element {
  const [data, loading, error, fetch] = useAxios(...);
  const [data1, loading1, error1, fetch1] = useAxios(...);

  return (
    ... more sub-components
  );
}
```

And it is nested like so.

So basically a lot of data is obtained when the user navigates to componentA with react-router. My problem is that the user frequently navigates away from componentA (which is the main page), only to come back to componentA each time. Each time, componentA loads all of the data that was loaded previously, with only some minor changes made from users. This repeated loading is causing a ton of latency during navigation.

I don't feel I can take advantage of useMemo or useCallback since componentA is being unmounted during navigation by react-router. I don't feel persisting data in localStorage would be a good long term fix. I also feel that abstracting all the deep API calls within componentA to a higher order component would not be a great fix either and would cause a mess of the code with prop drilling.

So my question is how does one fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

save fetched data into redux, or create a CacheContext in the top, and create interceptor for axios to save fetched data on response, try use cache in request

Answer (score 0):

> I don't feel persisting data in localStorage would be a good long term fix

I don't think there's something wrong with using localStorage for this use-case.

> not be a great fix either and would cause a mess of the code with prop drilling

React offers a painless way to handle prop drilling, it's native and built-in to the language and it's called [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). There are some caveats to this as this requires optimizations and if not used properly, could lead to [issues](https://leewarrick.com/blog/the-problem-with-context/) such as (but not limited to) re-rendering unnecessarily. State management libraries like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree) gives you a way to handle this in a less painful way by simply connecting your component to the state tree which could be persisted in your local storage.

Another way to handle this is to simply cache your API's response, there are libraries out there like [SWR](https://github.com/zeit/swr) (stale-while-revalidate) built to simplify this for you.

A snippet from SWR's documentation:

> SWR first returns the data from cache (stale), then sends the fetch request (revalidate), and finally comes with the up-to-date data again.

There are also parameters in the library that allows you to dictate when to re-validate.